# Set Theory: Distributive laws with respect to the subtraction of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

"Prove that $A \cap (B - C) = (A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$"

Now what I do is the following, and what I get is a bit different.
We know that for some arbitrary member $x$, $x \in A$ and simultaneously $x \in B$, and $x \not \in C$. So since $x \in A$, $x \in B$, $x \not \in C$ we have that $(A \cap B) - C$.

But that's different from what I was trying to prove, right? Now obviously I could extend this to $(A \cap B) - (A \cap C)$, and that is arbitrary to do from the first result I got.

I still suspect I did something wrong though.

Comment: What do you mean by Now obviously I could extend this to (A∩B)−(A∩C), ?

Comment: Because it doesn't change anything about the statement, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in A\cap(B- C)$

$\iff$ $x\in A$  and $x\in(B- C)$

$\iff$  $x\in A$  and     $(x\in B$ and $x\not\in C)$,

$\iff$  $(x\in A$ and $x\in B)$ and $ (x\in B$ and $x\not\in C)$ (this is the important step)

$\iff$  $x\in(A\cap B)$ and $x\not\in(B\cap C)$

$\iff$  $x\in(A\cap B)-(B\cap C)$

Therefore the required equality follows.

Comment: But in step 3 can't we just say that:
$(x \in A$ and $x \in B) and (x \not \in C)$?

Comment: Yes, we can say, but that won't help you to prove your desired result.

Comment: How do you justify the third step?

Answer (score 3):

$A∩(B−C) = A∩(B∩C') = $

$B∩(A∩C') = B∩(A∩C' ∪ ∅) = $

$B∩[(A∩C') ∪ (A∩A')]= B∩A∩(A'∪C') = $

$(A∩B)∩(A∩C)' = (A∩B) - (A∩C) $